# How to convert special characters from .PDF to .TXT in C# using iTextSharp?

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itext, pdf-reader

I got the CODE-SUN.pdf document.
I extracted the text from this document using the below source code.
The extracted text is different from the CODE-SUN.pdf document.
For example, it was extracted "commi\0ed" instead of "committed".

Please see the attached CODE-SUN.pdf document: https://www.dropbox.com/s/p88695vel6zaa86/CODE-SUN.pdf?dl=0

I've tried the below source code:

```
public static string ConvertToTxtWithITextSharp(byte[] content)
{    
    var pdfReader = new PdfReader(content);

    var s = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var pageNo in Enumerable.Range(1, pdfReader.NumberOfPages))
    {
        s.AppendLine($"** Page {pageNo} **");
        ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();              
        var currentText = "";

        currentText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfReader, pageNo, strategy);

        currentText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.Convert(Encoding.ASCII, Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Default.GetBytes(currentText)));
        s.AppendLine(ConcatLines(currentText));
    }            

    return s.ToString();
}
```

The desired result is to extract the correct text from any .pdf document.

Comment: That's a sample from the CODE-SUN.pdf document that I use as text input:
"Sun Pharma is committed to complying with all applicable environmental legislation and other environmental requirements to which we subscribe, and to the continual improvement of the environmental management system to enhance environmental performance."

Comment: Apparently your pdf text uses ligatures but doesn't add the required information for text extraction. Please share the pdf in question for analysis.

Comment: Thank you mkl, I shared the CODE-SUN.pdf document.

Comment: As assumed the PDF uses ligature glyphs (glyphs representing multiple characters at once, e.g. the 'tt' in 'committed') but in the respective **ToUnicode** mapping (which tells text extractors which unicode character(s) a glyph corresponds to) that glyph is neither mapped to the Unicode values a pair of 't's nor to that of a 'tt' ligature; instead it is mapped to U+0000. Unfortunately other ligature glyphs also are mapped to U+0000, e.g. the 'ti' in 'legislation' later in your example text, so you cannot simply replace all '\u0000' by 'tt'.

Comment: Thus, pure simple text extraction won't return you the desired text. In case of *this* document, though, there is a way out: the text drawing instructions with ligature glyphs are preceded by marked content points containing the actual Unicode for glyph string to come. You cannot expect this from arbitrary PDFs, though. Concerning *"The desired result is to extract the correct text from any .pdf document"*, therefore: there is no common routine for that.

Comment: As an aside, what do you attempt in the `currentText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.Convert(Encoding.ASCII, Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Default.GetBytes(currentText)))` line?

Comment: Thank you mkl! That line of code is the assurance of getting the correct characters (encoding ASCII to UTF-8), from any selected text, for any document.pdf, written in any world's language.

Comment: I also tried to select random text, from CODE-SUN.pdf document, (for copy-paste reason), using Adobe Acrobat Reader standard document management system. 
But when I pasted the text inside a file.txt, some characters of the original text were wrong represented. 
(e.g. "commied" instead of "committed")

Comment: *"That line of code is the assurance of getting the correct characters"* - hhmmm, to me that looks more like code attempting to damage everything except probably ASCII and probably other single-byte UTF-8 characters. Do you by chance have an example PDF in which that line improves the output?

Comment: *"I also tried to select random text, from CODE-SUN.pdf document using Adobe Acrobat Reader"* - Adobe Reader copy&paste essentially does the same text extraction as iText does; thus, it also has issues at the broken glyphs in your pdf.

Comment: Thank you mkl!
"Do you by chance have an example PDF in which that line improves the output?" - Unfortunately, I don't have any example. Therefore, you're right.